# How to display data on show page by fetching from new and create actions in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller, fetch

Hi am using rails and trying to fetch the data after clicking on submit button , but my data is not saving after pressing the submit button, kindly let me know how can i display data on show.html.erb after saving: here is the code of:

articles_controller.erb:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController



  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end



  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def new
    @article=Article.new
  end



  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  end

  private

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description)
  end
end
```

new.html.erb:

```
<h1>Create new File</h1>

<%= form_with scope: :article, url: articles_path , local: true do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title, "Title" %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :description, "Description" %><br/>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit %> </p>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb:

Rails.application.routes.draw do

```
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  root "articles#index"
  resources :articles, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy, :index, :new]

end
```

show.html.erb:

```
<h1>show</h1>
<h3><strong>Title: </strong><%= @article.title %></h3>
<h3><strong>Description: </strong><%= @article.description %></h3>
```

Comment: Try `form_with model: @article do |f|`

Comment: @mechnicov still does not work

Comment: See logs. Look at the params, rollback there

Comment: You don't even have the create route allowed, and your form is submitting to the index action. Why not use the scaffold generator to get a working example to learn from.

Comment: i've never seen a tutorial or any blog post or rails guide that would teach you to do what you're doing. AI code? - of course it doesn't work.

Comment: @Alex i am doing this course from udemy, and i don't know where i am wrong i did almost everything that my tutor did in that video.

Comment: @smathy thank you , this was the issue that i did not define create route in resourses

Comment: @smathy this isn't actually the case. `form_with` defaults to `method="POST"` and posting to the collection path will route to the create action.

Comment: @max i have seen your answer its impressive, but sir when i write the code of validation in new.html.erb , it do not displainng any error on screen, however when i try to get the errors on rails console, it display, the error is only not showing on screen, however when i enter data in filelds it save the appropriate record untill i disobay the validation.

Comment: @AfaqKhan I can't actually see your code and hand hold you through this process. This isn't 1:1 tutoring. This is really super basic rails stuff that's covered by the [getting started guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-a-new-article) as well as the [guides article on validations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-views). Whatever issue you're having its unlikely that its because of errors in the code in my answer.

Comment: @max please see this code: 
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5mup.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255564/discussion-between-afaq-khan-and-max).

Answer (score 2):

Whatever tutorial you're following - I don't think its very good.

Do not just assume that creating or updating a record will succeed (When you assume, you make an ...). Users will input invalid input and you need to deal with that:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  # ...

  # POST /articles
  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render :new # render the form again but with error messages
    end
  end

  private

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description)
  end
end
```

You also need to let `resources` generate the `POST /articles` route for the create action:

```
# there is no point in using "only" when you're generating everything
resources :articles
```

You also want to use the form helpers in the resource oriented style:

```
<%= form_with model: @article do |f| %>
  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
        <% @article.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title, "Title" %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :description, "Description" %><br/>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

This will bind the inputs to the model so when the validations fail the form isn't blanked out which will make your users very unhappy. We are also displaying the error messages in the form if any validation fails.

Rails is convention over configuration driven. You do not need or want to configure the URI, scope or anything else unless you have a strong reason to do so.

Rails will figure out by looking at the model which path to use (`/articles` or `/articles/:id`) for the form action and the correct HTTP method.

The basic CRUD operations in [Rails are well covered by the official guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-a-new-article).

Answer (score 1):

**Update** I spend a minute longer reading your code. Please make sure to read the comments to your question, the folks give good insights.

**what it is that does not work** and how did you came to that conclusion? I assume that some page renders that shows an error.

Skimming your code gives the impression that it should roughly do what you expect, *but*: you do not check whether `@article.save` in the create action works (thanks by sharing all the code btw, that makes answering easier). `save` (and `update`, `create`) will return `true` or `false` to tell you whether saving to database worked.

To get something that works, as a basis: If you use the *rails generators to scaffold a resource* (`rails g scaffold MyThing name:string`), you should see how this works in its simplest default case. You can later remove the scaffold code by hand or call `rails d scaffold MyThing`).

Hope that helps. Maybe there are other underlying issues as well (*Update, there are*), but *always* make sure to check the return values of `create, update, save`. Also, instead of using `new + save`, you could use `@article = Article.create(article_params)` (or, for debugging `... cle.create!(...` with the bang).

You *could* call `@article.save!` (with the "bang": !) which will throw an exception if it does not work (fine for debugging). Same goes for other "bang!"-variants (`create!, update!, save!`), they throw an exception. However, using exceptions to control flow is debated/discouraged. Especially for beginners it might be a good practice to always check and handle the return code (thanks max for the comment).

Comment: IMHO telling beginners to use the bang methods doesn't actually do them any favors. The bang methods should only be used in cases where a record failing to be created should be an exceptional event like in seed files or non-user interaction contexts. It's better that they learn [how to debug by using breakpoints](https://github.com/ruby/debug#how-to-use) or just setup the form to display validation errors (and write a test that covers it).

Comment: Fair comment @max. I will slightly modify the answer. However, the bang-idiom is found in pretty shallow layers of the ActiveRecord-toolbox.